# What object is .getElementById() originally attached to?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to modify the prototype of whatever object is responsible for `.getElementById()`

I know `document` does not have a prototype, so what object is `.getElementById()` actually attached to?

Edit: so turns out document does have a prototype (thanks Kevin). I feel silly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is false that `document` does not have a prototype.

Regarding the `getElementById` method, I don't know what specifications have to say, but the location *differs between Safari and Firefox*, so it should be treated as an implementation detail. **Do not rely on the location of the definition**. You can always override it directly on `document`.

That said, I investigated and on Firefox 8.0, the method is defined on `document`'s prototype:

```
◀ Object.getPrototypeOf(document).hasOwnProperty("getElementById")
▶ true
◀ Object.getPrototypeOf(document)
▶ [xpconnect wrapped native prototype]
```

On Safari (and therefore probably also Chrome and other WebKit derivatives), it is on `document`'s prototype's prototype:

```
› document.hasOwnProperty("getElementById")
  false
› Object.getPrototypeOf(document).hasOwnProperty("getElementById")
  false
› Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(document)).hasOwnProperty("getElementById")
  true
› Object.getPrototypeOf(document)
  HTMLDocumentPrototype
› Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(document))
  DocumentPrototype
```

You can do research of your own using the browsers' object inspectors to look up the prototype chain, or using `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `hasOwnProperty`.

---

To override `document.getElementById` while keeping the original around, do something like this:

```
var originalGEID = document.getElementById;
document.getElementById = function (id) {
    ...
    var originalElement = originalGEID.call(document, id);
    ...
};
```

Note that this operates regardless of where the original method is in the prototype chain.

Answer (score 4):

It's attached to the `document` object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById

Comment: Really? Fooled me. "so what object is .getElementById() actually attached to?"

Comment: It is document.constructor.prototype. He said he knows about document, and wanted to know the *origin* of the function.

Comment: @pimvdb Turns out it isn't necessarily. (See my answer.) Also, `Object.getPrototypeOf` (new in ES5) is more reliable than `.constructor.prototype`.

Answer (score -1):

It is part of the Document prototype, here is an image to show that: [getElementById belongs to Document](http://imgur.com/SSVjI)
Use the following to define your own function for getElementById:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

  document.getElementById = function( id ) {

    alert( id );
  };
});
```

Comment: I believe he wants to know how to override the default getElementById function which is attached to the document object.